# ¿Cómo puedo pausar un translate animation y reanudarlo? pause(), resume() Android Studio

Tags: java, android, animación, traducción

Tengo una animacion tipo translate con un ImageView en bucle, por lo que se repite en infinite de izquierda a derecha. Mi duda es: si tengo un boton de pause, como puedo pausar o congelar dicha animacion conservando la posicion en el momento que lo presiono? y luego con otro boton reanudar la animacion?
He pensado en implementar un hilo, pero creo que debe existir algun metodo mejor.

si la solucion existe podria incorporar dichos metodos en el onclick.

```
public class Juego1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imgmov;
ImageButton play;
ImageButton pause; 
ImageButton stop;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_animaciontranslate);

    imgmov = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_pony2);
    play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_play_mov);
    pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_pause_mov); 
    stop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop_mov);


    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            play();
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Iniciando movimiento", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast1.show();
        }
    });

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            pause();

            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pausado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast2.show();
        }
    });

}

public void play(){
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.trans);
        imgmov.startAnimation(animation);
}


  public void pause(){

}

protected void stop() {
    imgmov.clearAnimation();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen dia @Mr K. Te recomiendo usar en lugar de TranslateAnimation ObjectAnimator ya que los cambios realizados sobre la imagen se realizan en tiempo real. Y es más fácil pausar y continuar la animación.

```
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imgmov;
    private Button play, pause, stop;

    //Posición inicial de la imagen
    private float startValue = 0f;
    //Posición final 
    private float finishValue = 500f;
    //Duración de la animación
    private long duration = 10000;

    private ObjectAnimator animator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgmov = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_pony2);
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

        animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgmov, "translationX",
                startValue, finishValue);
        animator.setDuration(duration);
        animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (animator.isPaused()) {
                    animator.resume();
                } else {
                    animator.start();
                }
            }
        });

        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (animator.isRunning()) {
                    animator.pause();
                }
            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                animator.cancel();
                imgmov.setTranslationX(0);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias por tu ayuda, realmente era lo que necesitaba :))
Puedo guardar en variables la posición exacta de la imagen cuando se pausa la animación cierto?

Comment: De nada compañero. Lo que dices lo puedes hacer con los métodos getX () y getTranslateX () échale un vistazo ya que los dos son parecidos a ver cual se ajusta mas a tus necesidades.